# How to get the content of ckeditor5 when user presses Enter in the editor?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor5

Now I am saving the content of the editor upon blur

```
                       onBlur={(event, editor) => {
                            const data: any = editor.getData();
                            void onCKEditorEntityBlur("Editing", data);
                        }}
```

Users prefer I use Enter instead.
It tried

```
                     onKeyDownCapture={(event, editor) => {
                            const data: any = editor.getData();
                            void onNoteKeyDownCapture("Editing", data);
                        }}
```

But pressings Enter, does not go to the onNoteKeyDownCapture function
What is the best way to capture the Enter event?
Thank you

Comment: If you saved on enter, how would a user enter a new line in the editor? You might want to question this request.

Comment: They are used to to Shift enter from Teams. :-)and Ckeditor adds a line with control and alt enter too